# Regex doesn't work

Tags: c#, regex

Hi guys I have next text:

```
</form>onclick="g(null,null,'.htaccess','touch')">Touch</a> <br><br><pre class=ml1>
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</pre></div>
```

I try to parse all between `<pre class=ml1>` and `</pre></div>` with: -

```
string con = Regex.Match(content, @"<br><br><pre class=ml1>(.*?)</pre></div>", RegexOptions.Multiline).Groups[1].Value;`
```

But it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
RegexOptions.Singleline
```

so the `.` matches every character *including* newlines.

You don't need `RegexOptions.Multiline` as you're not using `^` or `$`. (Multiline mode makes them match the beginning and end of a line, instead of the beginning and end of the input string.)

Answer (score 0):

The Only problem with your code is you have used Regex.MultiLine which should have been Regex.SingleLine

```
string con = Regex.Match(content, "<br><br><pre class=ml1>(.*?)</pre></div>", RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].Value;
```

---

### RegexOptions.MultiLine

> Multiline mode. Changes the meaning of ^ and $ so they match at the
> beginning and end, respectively, of any line, and not just the
> beginning and end of the entire string.

### RegexOptions.SingleLine

> Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it
> matches every character (instead of every character except \n).